# jQuery equivellent for dynamically create id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking for jQuery equivellent for the following. Please help.

```
var request = document.getElementById('request_' + id1)
var response = document.getElementById('response_' + id1); 
modifyText(request.firstChild.nodeValue,response.firstChild.nodeValue);
```

Comment: @user837593 If you can use raw javascript (I don't know why you can't) it will almost always be better.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
var request = $('#request_' + id1)
var response = $('#response_' + id1); 
modifyText(request.find(':first-child').text(),response.find(':first-child').text());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var request = $('#request_' + id1);
var response = $('#response_' + id1);
```